# Unable to execute IIS Administration commands on remote machine from Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) Build

Tags: powershell, azure, iis, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I have a set of power-shell scripts for managing the entire deployment. We migrated our entire codebase to Visual Studio Team Services (previously VS Online) and I am trying to get the entire deployment automation.

The steps I am following on high level are :

- Restore the packages and build the solutions
- Package the artifacts required in to a single folder (includes binaries, scripts, dacpac etc)
- Copy the package to a azure vm using azure file copy
- Execute the scripts on target machine

[image: Build Steps]

The issue I am facing is - none of the IIS Administration commands are executing on the remote machine. 
e.g. Remove-WebSite/Remove-WebAppPool are not working.

I do not see any error also being thrown by these commands.

Is there anything specific which needs to be enabled to run these commands.

**NOTE :** I am able to get the same scripts working fine when I run from the server directly. The issue is only when I am using the run 'powershell on target machine' on build steps of Team Services.

Comment: Have you enabled WinRM on the target machines. The task uses WinRM to execute powershell commands from the agent machine. Also make sure the target machines are reachable from the agent machine.

Comment: Also post the errors

Comment: @HarshilLodhi, WinRM is enabled, I am using a classic azure vm instance which has WinRM enabled by default. I am able to run the other scripts for setting up of the database etc. Its only on the IIS administration I am facing the issues. Unfortunately, even on the verbose I don't see any errors

Comment: Login to the agent box if you aren't using hosted agents. Create a WinRM session from there to the azure vm instance and see if the commands fail or not ? You can also take a look at the source code on GitHub if you are willing to debug it yourself. I think if the other commands are getting executed, the problem seems to be WinRM + IIS rather than the task's logic.

Comment: @SharathChandra Check whether there is detail error message in the log file (in _dialog folder of agent) if you are not using hosted agents.

Comment: @s09, I was able to fix this issue. I ran the quickconfig on winrm and restarted the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, the solution is run quickconfig on winrm and restart the machine.

Comment: Yes that appears to be the solution for the issue I had.